# STRIPE integration

Tags: delphi, stripe-payments

I'm using the REST Debugger as a first try at working with the stripe API. I can login and perform some basic creation and listing tasks.
When creating a customer the (postal) address elements are described as parameters that are of type 'dictionary'. The docs (https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers/create) refers to them as 'child parameters' with a notation address.line1, address.city etc. I'm lost as to what this means in terms of a Delphi friendly syntax. Anyone got any clues to move me forward? Many thanks

Comment: Data from multiple tables come across in one REST result. Ex customer and address records (commonly one for billing, one for shipping) for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took a look at the PHP client sources, and I found that the parameters were [flattened](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-php/blob/51e95c514aff45616dff09791ca5b2f10cf5c4e8/lib/Util/Util.php#L178) with a key[subkey] scheme before being sent. So you should use the following parameter names for the address:

- `address[line1]`
- `address[city]`
- `address[country]`
- ...

Comment: Many thanks - that's what I was after. Works a treat. Not sure I would ever have figured that out!